# GraphQL mutation type missing in the response

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, typeorm

I built in my GraphQL API a `DeleteUserMutation` which should allow me to delete a user and have a response with a message but on the return, I'm getting an error:

```
SError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/graphql/mutations/user/delete-user.ts:21:9 - error TS2740: Type '{ responseCode: number; message: string; user: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'User': id, name, last_name, email, and 4 more.

21         return response;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried to achieve that when  a User is deleted and success in the response I see the message from my type `DeleteUserresponse`

```
export const DeleteUserResponse = gql`
    type DeleteUserResponse {
        responseCode: Number!
        message: String!
        user: User
    }
`;
```

The mutation should delete the user and if success shows the success values and if not shows the opposite and I tried in this way:

```
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { Entities } from '../../../entities/entities';

export const deleteUserMutation = {
    async deleteUser(_, { id }): Promise<typeof user> {
        const response = {
            responseCode: 500,
            message: 'Error, user not deleted',
            user: null,
        };

        const repository = getRepository(Entities.user);
        const user = await repository.findOne({ id });

        if (user && repository.delete({ id })) {
            response.responseCode = 200;
            response.message = 'User deleted successfully';
            response.user = user;
        }

        return response;
    },
};
```

But this above doesn't work and cannot understand what is the issue as I'm a newbie in GraphQL.
The error suggests the types are missing but I tried to play around adding and removing types but that error is not going away.

What is the issue in my code and how to fix it.

Comment: looks to me that `deleteUserMutation` return type is set to type `User`?

Comment: I believe your return type is wrong, `User` should contains `id`, `name` etc, but your `response` is `responseCode`, `message` and `user`. This is the typescript error instead of graphql, just change the `Promise<type user>` to something else should fix

Answer (score 0):

type Mutation{ deleteUserMutation(input:{}):Respone }
type Respone{responseCode: Number!message: String!user: User}
Please use above pattern

Comment: I fixed doing this `Promise<typeof deleteUserMutation>`

Answer (score 0):

I want to show my solution to my problem as based on comments I read on my question.

I changed the `typeof` as follow and that fixed the issue:

`Promise<typeof deleteUserMutation>`

Full code:

```
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { Entities } from '../../../entities/entities';

export const deleteUserMutation = {
    async deleteUser(_, { id }): Promise<typeof deleteUserMutation> {
        const response = {
            responseCode: 500,
            message: 'Error, user not deleted',
            user: null,
        };

        const repository = getRepository(Entities.user);
        const user = await repository.findOne({ id });

        if (user && repository.delete({ id })) {
            response.responseCode = 200;
            response.message = 'User deleted successfully';
            response.user = user;
        }

        return response;
    },
};
```